# What is string with square bracket in PHP

Tags: php

I saw the documentation of WordPress with `string[]`, what is this means?

It said "An array of...", but then the label for this is `string[]` instead of `array`.

I know the string in PHP is either `'Hello'` or `"Hello"`, what is `['Hello']`? Is this really a string?

Comment: That means "array of strings". `int[]` would mean "array of integers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`['Hello']` is an array with just one element that happens to be of type string. So if you e.g. do

```
  $a = ['Hello'];
  echo $a[0]."\n";
```

the output will be `Hello`.

`string[]` is basically saying: an array that only has strings stored in its element, no other types like e.g. `int`

So e.g.

```
  ['abc','xyz']
```

would be a valid `string[]` while

```
  ['abc', 123, 'xyz', 456]
```

would not be as it contains both `string` and `int` elements.

Answer (score 1):

`type[]` is the documentation convention that means "array whose elements are all `type`, so `string[]` means "array of strings". `["Hello", "World"]` is an example value.